# R: Find top, mid and bottom values to create a category column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a 'Category' column in the below dataset based on the sales and year.

```
set.seed(30)

df <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(2010:2015, each = 6),
  Country = rep(c('India', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA', 'Germany', 'Russia'), 6),
  Sales = round(runif(18, 100, 900))
)

head(df)

   Year Country Sales
1  2010   India   661
2  2010   China   888
3  2010   Japan   285
4  2010     USA   272
5  2010 Germany   332
6  2010  Russia   660
```

Categories are:

*Top 2 countries with highest sales in each year: Category - 1*

*Bottom 2 countries with lowest sales in each year: Category - 3*

*Remaining countries by year: Category - 2*

Expected dataset might look like:

```
   Year Country Sales Category
1  2010   India   661        1
2  2010   China   888        1
3  2010   Japan   285        3
4  2010     USA   272        3
5  2010 Germany   332        2
6  2010  Russia   660        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need much here; just `group_by` year, `arrange` from greatest to least sales, and then add a new column with `mutate` that fills with 2:

```
df %>% group_by(Year) %>% 
    arrange(desc(Sales)) %>% 
    mutate(Category = c(1, 1, rep(2, n()-4), 3, 3))

# Source: local data frame [36 x 4]
# Groups: Year [6]
# 
#     Year Country Sales Category
#    (int)  (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl)
# 1   2010   China   491        1
# 2   2010     USA   436        1
# 3   2010   Japan   391        2
# 4   2010 Germany   341        2
# 5   2010  Russia   218        3
# 6   2010   India   179        3
# 7   2011   Japan   873        1
# 8   2011   India   819        1
# 9   2011  Russia   418        2
# 10  2011   China   279        2
# ..   ...     ...   ...      ...
```

It will fail with fewer than four countries, but that doesn't sound like an issue from the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` to create a 'Category' column after grouping by "Year".

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(Category = as.numeric(cut(-Sales, breaks=c(-Inf, 
        quantile(-Sales, prob = c(0, .5, 1))))))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-Sales), Category := if(.N > 4) rep(1:3,
    c(2, .N - 4, 2)) else rep(seq(.N), each = ceiling(.N/3))  ,by = Year]
```

This should also work when there are fewer elements than 4 in each "Year". i.e. if we remove the first five observations in 2010.

```
df1 <- df[-(1:5),]
setDT(df1)[order(-Sales), Category := if(.N > 4) rep(1:3,
        c(2, .N - 4, 2)) else rep(seq(.N), each = ceiling(.N/3))  ,by = Year]
head(df1)
#   Year Country Sales Category
#1: 2010  Russia   218        1
#2: 2011   India   819        1
#3: 2011   China   279        2
#4: 2011   Japan   873        1
#5: 2011     USA   213        3
#6: 2011 Germany   152        3
```